# wampserver tray icon is missing

Tags: wampserver

I have had wamp server 2.2 installed in c: drive, (Windows 7), running Apache 2.2.9, Mysql 5.5.24 and PHP 5.3.1.

Then I re-installed it in another drive (d:) and transferred the data and www directory code there.

It worked ok for a while, with the localhost sites running perfectly, etc., but after a few days, the tray icon stopped displaying in the taskbar, when I run 'start Wampserver' in Start menu. Also, 'start Wampserver' shortcut icon is missing as well.

When I run it from the Start menu, I can see wampapache service running in the Services list, but wampmysqld is stopped. I can start it manually though, so eventually, wamp server runs ok, but with the tray icon in the taskbar missing and evidently, without having access to it's menu.

Also, when this issue first appeared, I noticed that 'wampmanager.exe' file was missing from wamp root directory and I needed to re-copy it there.

Is there any way I could retrieve the tray icon back without having to re-install wamp server again?

Comment: Did you install the same version again on the `D:\drive`, or a different version?

Comment: I installed the same version.

Comment: Open task manager, end the task AeTrayMenu. This is not kill web server and databases. Then reopen wampmanager.exe. This is fixed my problem.

Comment: The above comment solved my issue!. So in my case, this Q was NOT A DUPLICATE, and the question title perfectly described my exact situation. In my case, and I suspect for others who upvoted @HalilİbrahimOymacı Comment, the issue had nothing to do with Re-Installing WAMP (as I have not done so), and everything to do with the Ae TrayMenu task somehow "breaking" and needed restarted. I would like to propose re-opening the question, as it is not necessarily a duplicate, esp given the title. I have found NO other answers on the interned that worked. The above comment is a relevant, unique solution

Comment: All the answers couldn't help.not until i had to close the wampserver process in task manager, then run it as admin.Finally everything was stabilized to normal

Comment: Solution for this question is Just do windows10 updates. after update restart computer, then start wampserver64.

Comment: If for some reason none of the given solutions worked, try changing compatibily mode of the wampmanager.exe excecutable (C:\wamp64) to Windows 8, then kill all wamp processes by right-clicking running as admin > quit_wampserver.bat and reopen Wamp server, the icon will be shown again.

Answer (score 1):

Ok quite a bit of confusion here!

First it is not good to try to install WAMPServer more than once on the same PC. The second install will work and become the installation that is used but a few things go wrong.

The start menu and desktop shortcuts to start WAMPServer will probably still be pointing to the folder from the first install. So these probably disappeared when you eventually deleted the old `C:\wamp` folder.

You can re-create these very easily by going to `D:\wamp\` and making a shortcut of `wampmanager.exe` and putting that back onto your desktop and into the start menu.

Once you have these back, all should work again as you expect.

Comment: As I described in my question, I had already re-copied 'wampmanager.exe' in D:\Wamp, but when I run it, only the wampapache service was run, with the tray icon still missing.

Comment: The reason the Apache service was running is that on older versions of WAMPServer i.e. 2.2.x and 2.3 and 2.4 the wampapache service was installed with the `autostart` option set rather than the `manual` setting. WAMPServer 2.5 has fixed this situation and Apache is now installed with the MANUAL option. You can change the setting manually from the Services snapin `services.exe` if you wish, to make sure Apache only starts when you ask it to using the wampmanager.exe menus.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if "barimage.bmp" image is missing.

> > If missing please download it from >>>https://www.uploady.com/#!/download/8cG1gif5Y1E/gXfCRpWrU0qfo0g8
> >     and save it to wamp folder.
> >     And try again. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Do you have a more official looking link? Such as from WAMP or similar? This looks too spammy and insecure to click.  Also good answers always include an explanation. Why do you think this file will fix the OP's issue? Documentation? What is the underlying problem?